# Comparing screen data at client side

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Is there any way I can check whether the user has changed any data on the web page between the page load and save button click. If the user has opened any page to edit some data and clicks the save button without changing any data on the screen then I need to display a message.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are trying to do is check if the form is dirty  (i.E. something has changed) and [this dirty form](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/dirtyform) plugin might help you.

Answer (score 4):

I think setting a flag would be a good idea. Use global selectors to do such a thing.

```
var changed = false;
$("input").change(function(){
    //something changed
    changed = true;
});
```

Then if the users leaves the page, check if `changed` is `true`